# Discordjs: How to fix execute is not defined?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I started making a music bot for my discord server when i input command for playing song it returns that execute is not defined i tried to fix but i had no success. That's why I am asking here.

Note: I made event and command handler but that is not the problem since it was also not working before implementing it.

Here is my code from event that happens on message aka starting command:

```
module.exports = (client, Discord, message)=>{

    const prefix = '-';
    
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split('/ +/');
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

    //const ChannelName = message.channel.name;
    

    try{
        command.execute(args, cmd, client, Discord, message);
    } catch(err){
        message.reply("There was an error trying to execute this command!");
        console.log(err);
    }

    
}
```

And here is my code for play command:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');


const queue = new Map();

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['skip', 'stop'], 
    cooldown: 0,
    description: 'Advanced music bot',
    async execute(args, cmd, client, Discord, message){


       
        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voice_channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');

        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

      
        if (cmd === 'play'){
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
            let song = {};

            
            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = { title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
            } else {
                
                const video_finder = async (query) =>{
                    const video_result = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (video_result.videos.length > 1) ? video_result.videos[0] : null;
                }

                const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video){
                    song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
                } else {
                     message.channel.send('Error finding video.');
                }
            }

          
            if (!server_queue){

                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }
                
              
                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);
    
                
                try {
                    const connection = await voice_channel.join();
                    queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send('There was an error connecting!');
                    throw err;
                }
            } else{
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                return message.channel.send(` **${song.title}** added to queue!`);
            }
        }

        else if(cmd === 'skip') skip_song(message, server_queue);
        else if(cmd === 'stop') stop_song(message, server_queue);
    }
    
}

const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    
    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    song_queue.connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 0.5 })
    .on('finish', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
    await song_queue.text_channel.send(` Now playing **${song.title}**`)
}

const skip_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    if(!server_queue){
        return message.channel.send(`There are no songs in queue `);
    }
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

const stop_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    server_queue.songs = [];
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}
```

I think that problem is in main part of code but I cant seem to find problem.

Here is code for command handling

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of commandFiles){
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
        if(command.name){
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        } else{
            continue;
        }
        
    }
}
```

And here is my main file of the bot with commands collection

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    client.user.setStatus('online')
    console.log('Bot is online!');
    client.user.setActivity('Youtube',{
        type:"LISTENING"
    })
    console.log('Servers:')
    client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
        console.log('-' + guild.name)
    })
});



const fs = require('fs');
const message = require('./events/guild/message');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})
```

Comment: "I made event and command handler but that is not the problem since it was also not working before implementing it." - what does this mean, does your play command use the same format as the rest of your commands

Comment: yes it uses same format as rest of my commands but problem was there before me rewriting my command and event handler

Comment: The problem is more likely to be how you're requiring the commands, can we see your code where you initialise client.commands and require the files?

Comment: I edited the question with my command handler

Comment: Attach your commands collection please.

Comment: Added let me know if anything else needs to be added